# Arch VM constantly receiving Caps Lock signal

Tags: keyboard, vmware, arch-linux, xorg, capslock

edit: This seems to have been patched in the latest version of the vmware workstation.

So I was enjoying life for a while, but then vmware decided that my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key needed to be more non-deterministic.

This occurs across two different VMs (I created a new one just to ensure that it wasn't something I did on the old one).

When <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is enabled, it cannot be disabled. Sometimes if you type a long sequence of letters, it will turn off for a second, but then comes right back. I opened up `xev` to see what was going on, and sure enough, I was getting a constant stream of <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keypress events.

Another important fact: it doesn't happen in TTYs. Only in an X11 environment.

I thought it was my vmware host tools, so I updated them. No dice.

I reinstalled `open-vm-tools` on the guest, and triple checked to ensure they were enabled and all of the kernel modules are loaded. No dice.

I re-installed vmware entirely. No dice.

What could possibly be causing this? Here's a video I made in case my description isn't clear enough.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkMg6BoQhYg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with VMWare Workstation 15.5.5

A VMWare employee has suggested to set the configuration

```
mks.win32.useInjectedMagic=FALSE
```

as a workaround [here](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2953053#2953053) which solved the problem for me.

EDIT: According to the [15.5.6 Release notes](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.5/rn/VMware-Workstation-1556-Pro-Release-Notes.html#resolvedissues), this issue has been resolved.